# pymssql: executemany value error - expected a simple type, a tuple or a list

Tags: python, list, sql-server-2008, tuples, pymssql

```
grpidx_data=[]
for i in range(0,len(data1)):
    grpidx_data.append((data1.loc[i,'price'],data1.loc[i,'id']))
cur.executemany("insert into grpidx values (%s,%s)",grpidx_data)
```

I use python3.3 and pymssql. I want to import data from python to MSSQL. grpidx_data's type is **list(tuple)**,like[(12,1),(34,2),...], I run the code above then got the error:

> ValueError: expected a simple type, a tuple or a list

If I just use the data which type is **list(tuple)**, the code works fine. But when I use for loop got the data, even its type also **list(tuple)**,its not working.

So How to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Can u `print(grpidx_data)` to see its content?

Comment: `print(grpidx_data)`

[(40273730, 1.0), (50685730, 1.0), (52084730, 1.0), ...(36399702, 24.0)]

Comment: Did u try with `%d` instead of `%s` : `cur.executemany("insert into grpidx values (%d,%d)",grpidx_data)` ?

Comment: I have tried, and got the same error

Comment: What about this: `cur.executemany("insert into grpidx values (%s,%s)", *grpidx_data)` (Notice the star for unpacking before `grpidx_data` )

Comment: I think grpidx_data's type is wrong, but I dont know why. If I just use `cur.executemany("insert into grpidx values (%d,%d)",[(40273730, 1.0), (50685730, 1.0), (52084730, 1.0)])` its work! But when I change real number to `grpidx_data` , I will got the error

Comment: `cur.executemany("insert into grpidx values (%s,%s)", *grpidx_data)`
**TypeError: executemany() takes exactly 2 positional arguments (8622 given)**

Comment: Then there must be an item within `grpid_data` which is not a tuple of two elements...Try to verify your data before inserting it, with some sort of for loop...like a checking coding of the tuples.

Comment: Something like:
`for data in grpidx_data:
     if len(data) > 2:
         print(data)`

Comment: print nothing! There is not any item which length more than 2

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, actually having one script that ran and one that didn't. I eventually figured out that the one that was working was all strings and the other had numbers. Digging in further I was finding that the bad type was the **numpy.int64** type that numpy uses for integers. Looks like you are using pandas, which also has those number types. I forced it to a string, ran the code again and everything worked.

I wrote a special cleaning function to clean out the tuple before running it:

```
def tupleGetter(x):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if str(type(x[i])) == "<class 'numpy.int64'>":
            x[i] = str(x[i])
    return tuple(x)
```

Then I ran my code,  almost exactly like what you have above:

```
myValues = (tupleGetter(df.ix[i]) for i in range(len(df)))
cursor.executemany("""INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable([A],[B],[C],[C],[D],[E],[F])
 VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""",
    myValues
    )

conn.commit()
```

Ran no problem.

Be sure to `dropna()` as well because that is also a strange type.

Answer (score 4):

As billmanH pointed out, using a type that is not expected by pymssql can generate this error.

Converting to strings works when you want to store strings in the database but I wanted numbers.
By passing all as strings and converting on the SQL side, I had total control on 
the type of the data.

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO my_table(my_int_column, my_numeric_column) VALUES (CAST(%s AS INTEGER),  CAST(%s AS NUMERIC(19, 9)))",
my_tuple_containing_strings)
```

Comment: This is a good approach, however I've found that if the db is expecting numeric values it will coerce the string values into the proper numbers (same with dates and other things). However if you want to be sure that things are casting correctly this would be good QA.