# How to for loop INSERT value in list pymssql?

Tags: python, sql-server, pymssql

i try to insert data in for loop but it crashed after commit some data to database i assume that it because i try to INSERT to many data. so i want some suggestion to handle this problem

```
for value in list:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table_name (filed1, filed2, filed3, filed4, filed5) VALUES (%d, %d, %d, %d, %d)", (var1, var2, var3, var4, var5))
    conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

>

```
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO ScanEMAxEMAHistoryDay (SecurityNumber, EMA1, EMA2, CrossType, DayCross) VALUES (%d, %d, %d, %d, %d)", (id, item[0][0], item[0][1], value[0], value[1]))
  File "pymssql.pyx", line 449, in pymssql.Cursor.execute (pymssql.c:7184)
  File "_mssql.pyx", line 1011, in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.execute_query (_mssql.c:11594)
  File "_mssql.pyx", line 1042, in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.execute_query (_mssql.c:11474)
  File "_mssql.pyx", line 1159, in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.format_and_run_query (_mssql.c:12615)
  File "_mssql.pyx", line 1181, in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.format_sql_command (_mssql.c:12876)
  File "_mssql.pyx", line 1815, in _mssql._substitute_params (_mssql.c:20639)
  File "_mssql.pyx", line 1798, in _mssql._quote_data (_mssql.c:20347)
  File "_mssql.pyx", line 1768, in _mssql._quote_or_flatten (_mssql.c:19919)
ValueError: expected a simple type, a tuple or a list
```

Comment: Similar question with helpful answers: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38238936/5405967

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem. My input data type was float32. After I change it to float64, it works. You can take a try.